# Convert type of multiple columns of a dataframe at once

Tags: r, type-conversion

I seem to spend a lot of time creating a dataframe from a file, database or something, and then converting each column into the type I wanted it in (numeric, factor, character etc).  Is there a way to do this in one step, possibly by giving a vector of types ?

```
foo<-data.frame(x=c(1:10), 
                y=c("red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", 
                    "blue", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", 
                    "green"),
                z=Sys.Date()+c(1:10))

foo$x<-as.character(foo$x)
foo$y<-as.character(foo$y)
foo$z<-as.numeric(foo$z)
```

instead of the last three commands, I'd like to do something like

```
foo<-convert.magic(foo, c(character, character, numeric))
```

Comment: Use the `colClasses` argument to `read.table`.

Comment: Ranges of values can also be assigned simply using: `for(n in names(foo)[1:2]{foo[[n]]<-as.character(foo[[n]])}` Convenient for lots of columns to convert.

Comment: Learned if converting multiple fields from factor to numeric you will need another call to `as.character` or `levels`. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-an-integer-numeric-without-a-loss-of-information

Answer (score 35, accepted):

**Edit** See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11261399/324364) related question for some simplifications and extensions on this basic idea.

My comment to Brandon's answer using `switch`:

```
convert.magic <- function(obj,types){
    for (i in 1:length(obj)){
        FUN <- switch(types[i],character = as.character, 
                                   numeric = as.numeric, 
                                   factor = as.factor)
        obj[,i] <- FUN(obj[,i])
    }
    obj
}

out <- convert.magic(foo,c('character','character','numeric'))
> str(out)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ y: chr  "red" "red" "red" "blue" ...
 $ z: num  15254 15255 15256 15257 15258 ...
```

For truly large data frames you may want to use `lapply` instead of the `for` loop:

```
convert.magic1 <- function(obj,types){
    out <- lapply(1:length(obj),FUN = function(i){FUN1 <- switch(types[i],character = as.character,numeric = as.numeric,factor = as.factor); FUN1(obj[,i])})
    names(out) <- colnames(obj)
    as.data.frame(out,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}
```

When doing this, be aware of some of the intricacies of coercing data in R. For example, converting from factor to numeric often involves `as.numeric(as.character(...))`. Also, be aware of `data.frame()` and `as.data.frame()`s default behavior of converting character to factor.

Comment: +1 for posterity, although I don't understand what the difference is.

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen If you're referring to the use of `switch`, for me it's mostly aesthetic and makes the code easier to read. Not sure if there's any performance difference, although I suspect not.

Comment: +1 for recommending `lapply`.  I've struggled to optimise this type of problem in the past, and it turns out that the `[<-` operation is rather slow.

Comment: @Andrie How time flies. Now that `data.table` has `:=` that's the way to go for this question, should be much much faster. `[<-` was slow because it was copying the whole data.frame every time one column changed. If I add an answer, will need votes and then ask OP to change accept?

Comment: Does this function convert numeric factors to numeric (i.e 3.6 = 3.6, not the factor order number)? How to incorporate that into the function? I tried as.numeric(as.character), which does not work.

Comment: @MatthewDowle: mind posting the data.table solution? Haven't done to much with it yet, so this isn't necessarily a no-brainer for me. Sounds interesting, though.

Comment: @MattBannert Hi. A looped `set` as in the last edit in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16846530/403310) is the way I'd do this. Replace the `-` with a call to `as(...)`, or similar.

Comment: Is there a way to use the actual column names instead of partnering the type to the index?

Comment: I keep getting the error `Error in FUN(1:11[[11L]], ...) : could not find function "FUN1"`. Any thoughts of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @Mikko: did you ever figure out how to handle the as.numeric(as.character) issue?

Comment: @theforestecologist Yes. I added it as an answer to this thread.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to automatically detect the columns data-type rather than manually specify it (e.g. after data-tidying, etc.), the function [`type.convert()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.4.3/topics/type.convert) may help.

The function `type.convert()` takes in a character vector and attempts to determine the optimal type for all elements (meaning that it has to be applied once per column).

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x)))
```

Since I love `dplyr`, I prefer:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate_all(funs(type.convert(as.character(.))))
```

Comment: Your first option should probably be `df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) type.convert(as.character(x))`. I'd drop the `apply` option since it's usually intended to produce a matrix or array. You've misspelled `dplyr` in your third option. Finally, this isn't really an answer to the OP's question, but rather to a related question.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting tips. It took me a long time to find a feature like type.convert, so I thought placing it here on a similar issue that came up more frequently would help someone like me down the road.

Comment: fair enough, though worth perhaps looking at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254971/re-convert-data-types-in-r)

Comment: Alternative (less verbose and more informative) approach using ``readr`` package: ``df <- type_convert(df)``.

Answer (score 8):

I find I run into this a lot as well. This is about how you import data. All of the read...() functions have some type of option to specify not converting character strings to a factor. Meaning that text strings will stay character and things that look like numbers will stay as numbers. A problem arises when you have elements that are empty and not NA. But again, na.strings = c("",...) should solve that as well. I'd start by taking a hard look at your import process and adjusting it accordingly.

But you could always create a function and push this string through.

```
convert.magic <- function(x, y=NA) {
for(i in 1:length(y)) { 
if (y[i] == "numeric") { 
x[i] <- as.numeric(x[[i]])
}
if (y[i] == "character")
x[i] <- as.character(x[[i]])
}
return(x)
}

foo <- convert.magic(foo, c("character", "character", "numeric"))

> str(foo)
'data.frame':   10 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 $ y: chr  "red" "red" "red" "blue" ...
 $ z: num  15254 15255 15256 15257 15258 ...
```

Comment: Try replace the `if` statements with a call to `switch`, which can actually return the appropriate function: `switch(expr,character = as.character, numeric = as.numeric,...)`.

Comment: meh, write it as an answer so you can get bonus points :) I just whiped something up quick.

Answer (score 8):

I know I am quite late to answer, but using a loop along with the attributes function is a simple solution to your problem.

```
names <- c("x", "y", "z")
chclass <- c("character", "character", "numeric")

for (i in (1:length(names))) {
  attributes(foo[, names[i]])$class <- chclass[i]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into something like this with RSQLite fetch method... the results come back as atomic data types.  In my case, it was a date time stamp that was causing me frustration.
I found that the `setAs` function is very useful for helping make `as` work as expected.  Here is my small example case.

```
##data.frame conversion function
convert.magic2 <- function(df,classes){
  out <- lapply(1:length(classes),
                FUN = function(classIndex){as(df[,classIndex],classes[classIndex])})
  names(out) <- colnames(df)
  return(data.frame(out))
}

##small example case
tmp.df <- data.frame('dt'=c("2013-09-02 09:35:06", "2013-09-02 09:38:24", "2013-09-02 09:38:42", "2013-09-02 09:38:42"),
                     'v'=c('1','2','3','4'),
                     stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
classes=c('POSIXct','numeric')
str(tmp.df)
#confirm that it has character datatype columns
##  'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
##    $ dt: chr  "2013-09-02 09:35:06" "2013-09-02 09:38:24" "2013-09-02 09:38:42" "2013-09-02 09:38:42"
##    $ v : chr  "1" "2" "3" "4"

##is the dt column coerceable to POSIXct?
canCoerce(tmp.df$dt,"POSIXct")
##  [1] FALSE

##and the conver.magic2 function fails also:
tmp.df.n <- convert.magic2(tmp.df,classes)

##  Error in as(df[, classIndex], classes[classIndex]) : 
##    no method or default for coercing “character” to “POSIXct” 

##ittle reading reveals the setAS function
setAs('character', 'POSIXct', function(from){return(as.POSIXct(from))})

##better answer for canCoerce
canCoerce(tmp.df$dt,"POSIXct")
##  [1] TRUE

##better answer from conver.magic2
tmp.df.n <- convert.magic2(tmp.df,classes)

##column datatypes converted as I would like them!
str(tmp.df.n)

##  'data.frame':  4 obs. of  2 variables:
##    $ dt: POSIXct, format: "2013-09-02 09:35:06" "2013-09-02 09:38:24" "2013-09-02 09:38:42" "2013-09-02 09:38:42"
##   $ v : num  1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to `type.convert(foo, as.is = TRUE)` there is also `readr::type_convert` which converts the dataframe to appropriate class without specifying them

```
readr::type_convert(foo)
```

---

If you keep all columns as character we could also use `readr::parse_guess` which would automatically convert the dataframe into correct classes. Consider this modified dataframe

```
foo <- data.frame(x = as.character(1:10), 
                  y = c("red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "yellow", 
                     "yellow", "yellow", "green"),
                  z = as.character(Sys.Date()+c(1:10)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

str(foo)

#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ x: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
# $ y: chr  "red" "red" "red" "blue" ...
# $ z: chr  "2019-08-12" "2019-08-13" "2019-08-14" "2019-08-15" ...
```

Applying `parse_guess` on each column

```
foo[] <- lapply(foo, readr::parse_guess)

#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ x: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# $ y: chr  "red" "red" "red" "blue" ...
# $ z: Date, format: "2019-08-12" "2019-08-13" "2019-08-14" "2019-08-15" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Addition to @joran's answer, in which `convert.magic` would not preserve numeric values in factor-to-numeric conversion:

```
convert.magic <- function(obj,types){
    out <- lapply(1:length(obj),FUN = function(i){FUN1 <- switch(types[i],
    character = as.character,numeric = as.numeric,factor = as.factor); FUN1(obj[,i])})
    names(out) <- colnames(obj)
    as.data.frame(out,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

foo<-data.frame(x=c(1:10), 
                    y=c("red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", 
                        "blue", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", 
                        "green"),
                    z=Sys.Date()+c(1:10))

foo$x<-as.character(foo$x)
foo$y<-as.character(foo$y)
foo$z<-as.numeric(foo$z)

str(foo)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ x: chr  "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
# $ y: chr  "red" "red" "red" "blue" ...
# $ z: num  16777 16778 16779 16780 16781 ...

foo.factors <- convert.magic(foo, rep("factor", 3))

str(foo.factors) # all factors

foo.numeric.not.preserved <- convert.magic(foo.factors, c("numeric", "character", "numeric"))

str(foo.numeric.not.preserved)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ x: num  1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 2
# $ y: chr  "red" "red" "red" "blue" ...
# $ z: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

# z comes out as 1 2 3...
```

Following should preserve the numeric values:

```
## as.numeric function that preserves numeric values when converting factor to numeric

as.numeric.mod <- function(x) {
    if(is.factor(x))
      as.numeric(levels(x))[x]
  else
      as.numeric(x)
}

## The same than in @joran's answer, except for as.numeric.mod
convert.magic <- function(obj,types){
    out <- lapply(1:length(obj),FUN = function(i){FUN1 <- switch(types[i],
    character = as.character,numeric = as.numeric.mod, factor = as.factor); FUN1(obj[,i])})
    names(out) <- colnames(obj)
    as.data.frame(out,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

foo.numeric <- convert.magic(foo.factors, c("numeric", "character", "numeric"))

str(foo.numeric)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ x: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# $ y: chr  "red" "red" "red" "blue" ...
# $ z: num  16777 16778 16779 16780 16781 ...

# z comes out with the correct numeric values
```

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat simple data.table solution, though it will take a few steps if you are changing to a lot of different column types.

```
dt <- data.table( x=c(1:10), y=c(10:20), z=c(10:20), name=letters[1:10])

dt <- dt[, lapply(.SD, as.numeric), by= name]
```

This will change all the columns except those specified in `by` to numeric (or whatever you set in `lapply`)

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution in the package `hablar`

#### Code

```
library(hablar)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(x = "1", y = "2", z = "4")

df %>% 
  convert(int(x, z),
          chr(y))
```

#### Result

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
      x y         z
  <int> <chr> <int>
1     1 2         4
```

You can simply put multiple column names to convert multiple columns, e.g. `z` and `z` to integer as in the example above.

Answer (score 0):

Transform is what you seem to describe:

```
foo <- transform(foo, x=as.character(x), y=as.character(y), z=as.numeric(z))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `purrr` and `base`:

```
foo<-data.frame(x=c(1:10), 
                y=c("red", "red", "red", "blue", "blue", 
                    "blue", "yellow", "yellow", "yellow", 
                    "green"),
                z=Sys.Date()+c(1:10))
types <- c("character", "character", "numeric")
types<-paste0("as.",types)
purrr::map2_df(foo,types,function(x,y) do.call(y,list(x)))
# A tibble: 10 x 3
   x     y          z
   <chr> <chr>  <dbl>
 1 1     red    18127
 2 2     red    18128
 3 3     red    18129
 4 4     blue   18130
```