# Function for converting dataframe column type

Tags: r, function, type-conversion

R often understands data frame columns in a "wrong" format or you just have to change the column class from factor to character in order to modify it. I have been changing the column class in following way previously:

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
y = rep(1:2, 5),
k = rnorm(10, 5,2),
z = rep(c(2010, 2012, 2011, 2010, 1999), 2),
j = c(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 3), "d"))

x <- c("y", "z")

for(i in 1:length(x)){
df[,x[i]] <- factor(df[,x[i]])}
```

And back to numeric:

```
x <- 1:5

for(i in 1:length(x)){
df[,x[i]] <- as.numeric(as.character(df[,x[i]]))} # Character cannot become numeric
```

It occurred to me that maybe there is a better way doing this. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680959/convert-type-of-multiple-columns-of-a-dataframe-at-once), which is almost exactly what I need:

```
convert.magic <- function(obj,types){
out <- lapply(1:length(obj),FUN = function(i){FUN1 <- 
switch(types[i],
character = as.character,
numeric = as.numeric,
factor = as.factor); FUN1(obj[,i])})
names(out) <- colnames(obj)
as.data.frame(out)
}
```

However, for this function vector type has to be specified for each column:

```
convert.magic(df, rep("factor",5))

convert.magic(df, c("character", "factor"))
# Error in FUN(1:5[[1L]], ...) : could not find function "FUN1"
```

Could somebody help me and rebuild this function so that it works with column names and numbers, please? I am afraid that this would be too advanced for me...

```
x <- c("y", "z")
convert.magic(df, "character", x)
```

Comment: If you're only converting factors to numeric, from `?factor`: "To transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values, as.numeric(levels(f))[f] is recommended and slightly more efficient than as.numeric(as.character(f))." That also indicates that `convert.magic` might produce unexpected results in certain circumstances.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10,
                 y = rep(1:2, 5),
                 k = rnorm(10, 5,2),
                 z = rep(c(2010, 2012, 2011, 2010, 1999), 2),
                 j = c(rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 3), "d"))

convert.magic <- function(obj, type){
  FUN1 <- switch(type,
                 character = as.character,
                 numeric = as.numeric,
                 factor = as.factor)
  out <- lapply(obj, FUN1)
  as.data.frame(out)
}

str(df)
str(convert.magic(df, "character"))
str(convert.magic(df, "factor"))
df[, c("x", "y")] <- convert.magic(df[, c("x", "y")], "factor")
```

Comment: This converts the entire data.frame. A slight modification is closer what I was after:
`convert.magic <- function(obj, type, cols){
  FUN1 <- switch(type,
                 character = as.character,
                 numeric = as.numeric,
                 factor = as.factor)
  obj[,cols] <- lapply(obj[,cols], FUN1)
  as.data.frame(obj)
}` How to add BenBarnes comment (`as.numeric(levels(f))[f]`) in this function?

Comment: @Largh Instead of using `as.numeric` in the `switch` statement you would probably write a simple wrapper that checks whether its input is a factor or not. If it is, use Ben's method, otherwise just use `as.numeric`.