# re-convert data types in R

Tags: r, type-conversion

I have a subset of data within a large dataset that does not conform to the original data types assigned when the data was read into R. How can I re-convert the data types for the subset of data, just as R would do if only that subset was read?

Example: imagine that there is one stack of data consisting of variables 1-4 (v1 to v4) and a different set of data starting with column names v5 to v8.

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4
1 32  a 11  a
2 12  b 32  b
3  3  c 42  c
4 v5 v6 v7 v8
5  a 43  a 35
6  b 33  b 64
7  c 55  c 32
```

If I create a new df with v5-v8, how can I automatically "re-convert" the entire data to appropriate types? (Just as R would do if I were to re-read the data from a csv)

Comment: How did you end up with that in the first place?  Might be best to find the problem that caused this and fix it so you don't have to do this again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try `type.convert`

```
df1 <- df[1:3,]
str(df1)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ V1: chr  "32" "12" "3"
# $ V2: chr  "a" "b" "c"
# $ V3: chr  "11" "32" "42"
# $ V4: chr  "a" "b" "c"

 df1[] <- lapply(df1, type.convert)
 str(df1)
 #'data.frame': 3 obs. of  4 variables:
 #$ V1: int  32 12 3
 #$ V2: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
 #$ V3: int  11 32 42
 #$ V4: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
```

To subset the `dataset`, you could use `grep` (as @Richard Scriven mentioned in the comments)

```
 indx <- grep('^v', df[,1])
 df2 <- df[(indx+1):nrow(df),]
 df2[] <- lapply(df2, type.convert)
```

Suppose, your dataset have many instances where this occurs, `split` the dataset based on a grouping index (`indx1`) created by `grepl` after removing the header rows (`indx`) and do the `type.convert` within the "list".

```
 indx1 <-  cumsum(grepl('^v', df[,1]))+1
 lst <- lapply(split(df[-indx,],indx1[-indx]), function(x) {
                x[] <- lapply(x, type.convert)
         x})
```

Then, if you need to `cbind` the columns (assuming that the `nrow` is same for all the list elements)

```
 dat <- do.call(cbind, lst)
```

Comment: I had actually tried type.convert before (i.e., before coming to stackoverflow) using sapply and it converted all of my character data to numeric, so I assumed it was not the right option. Any ideas why?

Comment: @AlexR `sapply` convert the output to `matrix` which can hold only one `class`.  So if there is any character column/element, it converts the whole matrix to `character` class. `lapply` is safer in that respect as it keeps the output in the list environment

Comment: Ah, I should have realized that myself. Thanks