# Automatically Assign Data Type in R

Tags: r, type-conversion

When I import .csv files into R, all the variables are in `character` format. Is there a way to automatically assign `numeric`, `factor`, and `character` types without having to manually do this for each column?

Comment: Please show what code you've used and a snapshot(copy-paste format or `dput`) of your data.

Comment: `df %>%
  convert(num(var1),
          dte(var2))`

Comment: Add the package `rio`(I assume) to your question and also what the data looks like and what you need to convert it to. It's currently ambiguous. Also why not use such functions as `as.numeric`?

Comment: You can do something like this in `dplyr`: `iris %>% 
 mutate_at(vars(c("Sepal.Length","Petal.Length")),list(as.double))`. The syntax is for the latest `dplyr` version. You can do some form of `regex` match for the column names to convert.

Comment: I know how to change each column individually, but I was wondering if there was a way to automatically assign data type or to assign multiple columns at once.

Comment: `readr::read_csv` handles most of it automatically, unless you have all columns in quotes

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680959/convert-type-of-multiple-columns-of-a-dataframe-at-once?rq=1)

Comment: Here is other code I used.

`cols_num = c("col_name")
df[,cols_num] %<>% 
  lapply(function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

I don't want to have to write in each column name

Comment: This works as well `df$var <- as.numeric(df$var)` but still doesn't solve the problem of automatically changing column data types

Comment: Try something like: `to_change<-grep("^S",names(iris))
as.data.frame(apply(iris[,names(iris)[to_change]],2,as.factor)))`. Although `read.csv` should automatically do these for you.

Comment: I get this error

`Error: unexpected symbol in "to_change<-grep("^S",names(iris)) as.data.frame"`

Comment: `read.table` and `read.csv` have the colClass argument where you can provide a character vector to define the types of each column. See `?read.table` for a description of this argument. If the automatic reader is interpreting these are characters, there may be a reason, such as one or more elements that can't be represented as numeric.

Comment: @bwn There's an extra bracket in the last call. My bad!