# Converting to string all values in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I make sure **each single value** contained in a dataframe is a **string**?

Moreover, is there a way I can **add a prefix** to each value contained in a dataframe? (for example, turning a `0.02` to `"X0.02"`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert type of multiple columns of a dataframe at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680959/convert-type-of-multiple-columns-of-a-dataframe-at-once)

Comment: Perhaps there's a better duplicate. The above is a bit too complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can loop through the columns of the `data.frame` with `lapply`, convert to `character` and assign the output back to the dataset.  The `[]` is used to preserve the attributes of the original data and not output as a `list` element

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, as.character)
```

Or if there is at least one character element, conversion to `matrix` and then back to `data.frame` will also make sure the elements are `character`

```
as.data.frame(as.matrix(dat), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

For the second case

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat,function(x) paste0("X", x))
```

---

Or in `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
dat %>%
   mutate_all(list(~ str_c("X", .)))
```

Comment: @iod To keep the shape (dimensions) of the dataset.