# Assign (different) column classes over data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to change column classes over my entire data.frame. Ideally looking for an `apply` solution, but open to `tidyverse` or other solutions as well.

**Example data**

```r
set.seed(1)
d <- data.frame("numbers" = as.character(1:10),
                "letters" = letters[1:10],
                "boolean" = sample(c("T", "F"), 10, T),
                stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I would like to make the first column (`numbers`) `numeric`, the second column (`letters`) `character`, and the third column (`boolean`) `logical`.

Comment: also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7680959/convert-type-of-multiple-columns-of-a-dataframe-at-once

Answer (score 5):

According to `?type.convert`, the usage is

> type.convert(x, ...)
>
> x - a vector, matrix, array, data frame, or list.

So, we can directly apply the `type.convert` on the `data.frame`.

```
d <- type.convert(d, as.is = TRUE)
str(d)
#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ numbers: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# $ letters: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
# $ boolean: logi  TRUE FALSE TRUE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...
```

---

Or another option is `type_convert` from `readr`

```
library(readr)
type_convert(d)
```

Answer (score 4):

One option without manually specifying class to convert is `readr::parse_guess` which automatically converts the vector to "best" type.

```
d[] <- lapply(d, readr::parse_guess)

str(d)
#'data.frame':  10 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ numbers: num  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# $ letters: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
# $ boolean: logi  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE ..
```

Or in base R, we can use `type.convert` with `as.is = TRUE`.

```
d[] <- lapply(d, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
```

Comment: no need for `lapply` in the second case, `type.convert(d, as.is = TRUE)` works

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper yes, I realised it later but there was a separate answer doing the same so didn't update.