# Specify column classes when reading in data via lapply(FileList, read.xls)

Tags: r, lapply, read.table

My question is about how to specify the class for various columns when reading in data that come from many files.  More specifically, I am uploading 1000s of .xlsx files at a time and converting them to .csv files using the `read.xls()` function in the `gdata` package.

My approach is as follows:

```
Myfiles<-list.files() # lists all files in working directory (which contains data files)
library(gdata)
Mylist <- lapply(Myfiles, read.xls, header=T,
    perl="C:/Users/A/PERL/perl/bin/perl.exe",
    sheet=1,
    method="csv",
    skip=1,
    as.is=1)
```

I apologize for not providing a workable example.  I'm not sure how to do so for this problem.

All the .xlsx files have identical headers and set-up, but the classes of corresponding columns in the data frames within `Mylist` are not all the same.  **Is there a way to specify the classes within the `lapply()` approach I am using?**  I know you can extend functions of `read.table()` to `read.xls()` but I haven't figured out how to specify the column classes properly within the `lapply` call.

Comment: Have you examined the actual data in the columns that dont seem to have the right class? My guess is that you have some offending characters in there that are mucking things up. You could also use `lapply()` over the resulting list and convert the columns there, as outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796266/change-the-class-of-many-columns-in-a-data-frame). Finally, if you're just writing back out to CSV, does it really matter?

Comment: Just read the help page for `read.xls()`. Looks like you can pass additional arguments via the `...` which go to read.table(). On the help page there, you'll see one of the parameters is `colClasses()` which can be one of the six atomic vector classes. These are defined on the help page for `?vector`.

Comment: The syntax is `lapply(Myfiles, read.xls, colClasses = c(...whatever...), ...whatever...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in Gabor's comment, but to put this one to bed:

```
lapply(Myfiles, read.xls, colClasses = c("character", "numeric", "factor"), header=T)
```