# Change class of multiple columns in data frame without for loop

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to change the class of multiple columns in an R data frame without either doing it one by one, or using a `for` loop (and noting [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796266/change-the-class-of-many-columns-in-a-data-frame) answer). I *can* do it with either of these methods, but they feel clumsy. Note that I don't necessarily want to change every column.

E.g. I have data frame `mydf`:

```
mydf <- data.frame("col1" = c(1, 2, 3),
               "col2" = c("a", "b", "c"),
               "col3" = c("a", "a", "b"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

I want to change columns two and three to class factor. (In reality I want to deal with many more than two columns...)

I can either do it column by column in my favourite way, e.g.:

```
mydf$col2     <- as.factor(mydf$col2)
mydf[, 3]     <- as.factor(mydf[,3])
```

Or I could use a for loop:

```
 for (i in 2:3{
   mydf[,i] <- as.factor(mydf[,i])
 }
```

These *work*, but feel clunky and suboptimal.

Better ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OK I worked it out while writing the question, but figured it might as well go up in case it's use to anyone in future:

```
mydf[,2:3] <- lapply(mydf[,2:3], as.factor)
```

Comment: This solution already appears in the linked question in here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3798348/3001626

Comment: For a more general use I think it's better to define a vector with the column names that should be converted, like `factor_cols <- c("col2","col3")`, followed by `mydf[factor_cols] <- lapply(mydf[factor_cols], as.factor)`

Comment: @RHertel thanks that's perfect advice

Comment: It's also appears in the linked answer.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I didn't check that, but I'm not surprised.