# as.numeric on subset of dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I convert columns 1 and 2 to numeric? I tried this which seemed obvious to me, but wasn't.

Thanks

```
df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,'x',4,5,6), v2 = c(1,2,'x',4,5,6), v3 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
as.numeric(df[,1:2])
```

Comment: `df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], as.numeric)`

Comment: `df[, 1:2] <- as.numeric(as.matrix(df[, 1:2]))`

Answer (score 3):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the columns of interest and convert to numeric

```
 df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this approach, using `unlist`. I particularly like the "one line" approach, when possible.And for more options and references, I strongly suggest this beautiful [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796266/change-the-class-of-many-columns-in-a-data-frame).

```
 df <- data.frame(v1 = c(1,2,'x',4,5,6), v2 = c(1,2,'x',4,5,6), 
 v3 = (1,2,3,4,5,6), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

 df[, c("v1","v2")] <- as.numeric(as.character(unlist(df[, c("v1","v2")])))
 Warning message:
 NAs introduced by coercion 

 str(df)
 data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
  $ v1: num  1 2 NA 4 5 6
  $ v2: num  1 2 NA 4 5 6
  $ v3: num  1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use matrix indexing without any hidden loops:

```
df[, 1:2] <- as.numeric(as.matrix(df[, 1:2]))
```