# R - convert dataframe columns to numeric - NAs introduced by coercion error

Tags: r

I am trying to execute the code from here:

[Change the class from factor to numeric of many columns in a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796266/change-the-class-from-factor-to-numeric-of-many-columns-in-a-data-frame)

in a dataframe with 140 columns

```
cols = c(1:140);    
merged_dataset[,cols] = apply(merged_dataset[,cols], 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)));
```

the problem is for some columns I get NAs. Is there a way somehow exclude these columns from the code so that I keep the data and they don't get transformed into NAs? I see the type of these columns is character if that helps.

Comment: Well presumably some of the factor/character data is not numeric and therefore can't be converted.  You should check your source data.

Comment: Yes how can I exclude these columns?

Comment: I think the better fix is to fix your data.  I mean, you are now saying that a column might or might not contain numbers.  You should already know this before casting.

Comment: I know which these columns are but how should I change my code to exclude them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know the indices of the columns you want to drop, then you may subset your data frame to target only certain columns:

```
cols <- c(1:140)         # all columns
cols.skip <- c(1,3,5,21) # columns which CAN'T be converted to numeric
cols.keep <- cols[!cols %in% cols.skip]
merged_dataset[,cols.keep] <- apply(merged_dataset[,cols.keep], 2, function(x) {
    as.numeric(as.character(x))
})
```

To implement similar logic using column names rather than indices:

```
cols.skip <- c("a", "b", "c")
cols.keep <- !(names(merged_dataset) %in% cols.skip)
merged_dataset[,cols.keep] <- apply(merged_dataset[,cols.keep], 2, function(x) {
    as.numeric(as.character(x))
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to write the columns with their names e.g. something like df[,"Name_of_column"] instead of numbers?

Answer (score 0):

Substitution of any improper characters inside factor levels can also occur to better extract any numbers:

```
convert_factors_to_numeric <- function(df) {

  as.data.frame(lapply(df,
                       function(x) {

                         if (is.factor(x)) {

                           as.numeric(as.character(trimws(x),
                                        which = "both"))

                         } else{

                           x

                         }
                       }
                     ),

                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

}

df_converted <- convert_factors_to_numeric(df)
```