# Convert multiple columns from factor to numeric but obtaining NAs in R

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion

Assuming the following dataframe `df`:

```
df <- structure(list(`week1` = structure(c(number = 4L, 
area1 = 1L, area2 = 2L, price1 = 3L, 
price2 = 5L), .Label = c("154.93", "304.69", "3554.50", 
"49", "7587.22"), class = "factor"), `week2` = structure(c(number = 3L, 
area1 = 1L, area2 = 4L, price1 = 2L, 
price2 = 5L), .Label = c("28.12", "2882.91", "30", 
"44.24", "4534.47"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("number", 
"area1", "area2", "price1", 
"price2"))
```

I'm try to convert its `week1` and `week2` columns from `factor` to `numeric` with:

```
cols = c(1, 2)
df[, cols] <- as.numeric(as.character(df[, cols]))
# df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], as.numeric) # gives incorrect results
```

Out:

[image]

But it returns `NA`s or incorrect results for those columns. However, the following code gives right answer:

```
cols = c(1, 2)   
df[, cols] = apply(df[, cols], 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
df
```

Out:

[image]

Why did I get `NA`s with the first solution which works for [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796266/change-the-class-from-factor-to-numeric-of-many-columns-in-a-data-frame)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`as.character`/`as.numeric` expects a vector as input. With `df[, cols]` you are passing a dataframe to it (check `class(df[, cols])`).

If you are talking about the accepted answer in the link it says to change the code in `for` loop and doesn't suggest to pass entire dataframe. To change class of multiple columns you can use `for` loop, `apply` or `lapply`.

```
df[cols] <- lapply(df[cols], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Comment: Thanks, could you pls explain what `2` represent in `apply(df[, cols], 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`?

Comment: 2 is to apply a function column-wise, 1 is for row-wise. Check `?apply`.

Comment: If I want to convert one row by its name from `float` to `integer`, I used `lapply(df['number', ], function(x) as.integer(x))` but not working, could you help? Which `function` should I choose?

Comment: You cannot convert one row to any class. In R, one column can have only one class. So you can either have integer or numeric column. You cannot have different classes in one column.