# Transforming string variables in base R

Tags: r

I have a data set for exploration. There are some string variables as well as  integer variables.

For the integer variables, I have to convert them to numeric. How do i transform the string variables?

[Structure of data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNAtn.jpg)

Comment: What exactly do you want to do to the string variable? You can transform data using `transform(movie)` but I don't think that's what you want to do. Unless I am mistaken

Comment: And you want to convert your integers into numeric?

Comment: Actually, I just checked each variable, not all the characters are actually character. For instance, Genre was meant to be a categorical variable (nominal), so i will be using the as.factor to make it usable by R. However, I still have variables like Director (which is a name), how do i make these type of variables useable? Sorry for not explaining properly

Comment: `type.convert(data, asis = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the class of data, you can convert `int` to `num` using the following. Note that you need to select the columns that you want to change. This answer came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3796655/9904275)

```
cols = c(1, 3, 4, 5);    
df[,cols] = apply(df[,cols], 2, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)));
```

Comment: Thank you. That's one of the things I need to do. How about the names e.g Director? They are still characters (string precisely). Can these be used as characters?